# How to change global git settings to do git merge during pull

Tags: git

Currently, my global settings are set to do a rebase during a git pull. I want it to change it to git merge by default. How do I change this setting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### TL;DR

```
git config --global pull.rebase false
```

### A bit detail

Git uses the configuration `pull.rebase` for this.

If you want to disable rebasing on pull, it can be set to false:

```
git config pull.rebase false
```

In order to do this globally, use

```
git config --global pull.rebase false
```

With this, git should do this for all repositories, unless configured otherwise.

If there is a local configuration, this will be overwritten.

Also, the `pull.rebase` option is overwritten by the `--rebase` option (`git pull --rebase`).

If you want to configure it for all users on your computer, you can execute

```
git config --system pull.rebase false
```

with administrative privileges.

This sets the default `pull.rebase` option for your system but it can be overwritten with `--rebase`, the local and global configuration.